# check if string is in abc order

Tags: python, string

So the function should count the number of times the letters in uppercase are out of abc order.

```
>>> abc('ABBZHDL')
    2
```

Above, z and d are out of order.

```
>>> abc('ABCD')
    0

>>> abc('DCBA')
    4
```

My code:

```
 def abc(check):
 order=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
   for c in check:
      if check != order:
   #then I get stuck here
```

Pointers?

Comment: Isn't it enough to just count how many times you go from a "higher" letter to a "lower" letter (assuming _consecutive_ "abc order")?  `'Z'`->`'H'` and `'H'`->`'D'`

Comment: I'm not sure how well-defined this question is. Are you trying to figure out if you sort the uppercase letters and compare them to the original, how many have changed place (example: `abc('ADBC') == 3`)? Or like Jeff asked, how many high to low transitions are in the letters (example: `abc('ADBC') == 1`)? Or how many swaps/moves are needed to sort the uppercase letters (this might actually work out to be the same as the second option, I'm not sure)?

Comment: `sed s/abc/lexicographic/g` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Comment: uhm, the L is also out of order in the first example.

Comment: @skyl: Apparently only "z and d are out of order."  So it appears the strings' letters should be in lexicographic order as Matt pointed out.

Comment: I don't get this distinction being made between lexicographic and "abc" order -- won't they be the same for the set of uppercase letters?

Answer (score 1):

The question is ill-defined.  One solution to a nearby question would be using the builtin sorted():

```
def abc(s):
    count = 0
    s = ''.join(i for i in s if i.isupper())
    l = sorted(s)
    for i,c in enumerate(s):
        if l[i] != c:
            count += 1
    return count
```

It counts all of the places where the alphabetized string does not match the original.

Comment: work for what I wonder.  I see that 3 letters need to move in abc('ABBZHDL') .. not 2 .. other than that ...

Answer (score 0):

```
def abc(check):
   last = ''
   count = 0
   for letter in check:
      if not letter.isupper():
           continue
      if letter < last:
           count += 1
      last = letter
   return count
```

Comment: Why is `order` declared?  I don't think string needs to be imported, either.

Comment: I get the idea of setting a counter, but when I tried this it didn't work.

Comment: @reve_etrange: yes no need for both -  I just removed them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

a = 'acbdefr'
b = 'abdcfe'

assert ''.join(sorted(b)) in string.ascii_letters
assert ''.join(sorted(a)) in string.ascii_letters #should fail
```

Its really simple everyone seems to be overcomplicating it somewhat?